# How to detect scrolling at the end of a listbox for N lists?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, listbox, scroll

I found [this approach by slimcode](http://blog.slimcode.com/2010/09/11/detect-when-a-listbox-scrolls-to-its-end-wp7/) which creates this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ListVerticalOffsetProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
  "ListVerticalOffset",
  typeof( double ),
  typeof( SearchBusinessResultsPage ),
  new PropertyMetadata( new PropertyChangedCallback( OnListVerticalOffsetChanged ) ) );

public double ListVerticalOffset
{
  get { return ( double )this.GetValue( ListVerticalOffsetProperty ); }
  set { this.SetValue( ListVerticalOffsetProperty, value ); }
}

private static void OnListVerticalOffsetChanged( DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e )
{
    // ...
}
```

It creates a single `readonly` property and a single static method to handle it. But I want to make N lists handle an event at the end of the scroll.

I don't know how to use this code to handle different lists...

Is there a better way of doing it? And how can I use the same thing for different lists?

Comment: Would this help? Assume you have updated your app to 7.1 http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slmperf/archive/2011/06/30/windows-phone-mango-change-listbox-how-to-detect-compression-end-of-scroll-states.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can create a BusinessListBox class that inherits from a ListBox and define its style and template as in the sample mentioned. You can then extend the DependencyProperty change handlers to have an instance change handler method.

```
private static void OnListVerticalOffsetChanged(
    DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var target = (BusinessListBox)d;
    double oldListVerticalOffset = (double)e.OldValue;
    double newListVerticalOffset = target.ListVerticalOffset;
    target.OnListVerticalOffsetChanged(oldListVerticalOffset, newListVerticalOffset);
}

private void OnListVerticalOffsetChanged(
    double oldListVerticalOffset, double newListVerticalOffset)
{
}
```

Ideally you would just implement a Behavior or attached property that would allow you to do the same on a regular ListBox.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add a handler for ScrollChangedEvent detection and use VerticalOffset property to find whether the scrolling has reached the end of the scroll.

```
 listBox.AddHandler(ScrollViewer.ScrollChangedEvent, new ScrollChangedEventHandler((o , e) => {
            ListBox lb = (ListBox) o;
            ScrollViewer sv = GetDescendantByType(lb, typeof(ScrollViewer)) as ScrollViewer;
            if (sv.ScrollableHeight == sv.VerticalOffset) { 
                //End of the scroll reached
            }
        }));
```

The helper method for finding the ScrollViewer in the ListBox

```
   /***
    * Helper method to traverse the root to find the the element of type `type`
    ***/
    public static Visual GetDescendantByType(Visual element, Type type) {
        if (element == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (element.GetType() == type) {
            return element;
        }
        Visual foundElement = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(element); i++) {
            Visual visual = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(element, i) as Visual;
            foundElement = GetDescendantByType(visual, type);
            if (foundElement != null) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return foundElement;
    }
```